# Displaying URL end in Laravel blade - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I have a response from an API which contains a link as below. 
`['link'] => items/892320`.
There are several link so I loop through to get all links.

In my view, I only want to display the last part of the URL i.e `892320` in the blade like below

**View**

```
@foreach($export_details['body']['data'] as $export_detail)
<div class="view">
    <div class="time">0:{{$export_detail['duration']}}</div>  
    <div class="time">0:{{$export_detail['name']}}</div>  
    <iframe src="{{$export_detail['link']}}" width="345" height="200" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
@endforeach
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $response = $client->request('/users/id/items', array(), 'GET');
    $results =  json_decode(json_encode($response),true);
    $export_details = $results;
    return view('home',compact('export_details'));  
}
```

How can I display just the last part of the url as my iframe source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that links will always follow the pattern 'items/{identifier}'

Use `ltrim` to remove 'items/' from beginning of link.

```
ltrim($export_detail['link'], 'items/')
```

Comment: can I use this in my view ?

Comment: Yes, you can use it in your view `<iframe src="{{ ltrim($export_detail['link'], 'items/')}}" width="345" height="200" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

If all the links you're receiving from the API are following the same format, you may achieve this by slightly adjusting your controller to massage the link before sending it to the view:

```php
public function index(){
  $response = $client->request('/users/id/items', array(), 'GET');
  $results =  json_decode(json_encode($response),true);
  $export_details = $results;
  $export_details['link'] = array_slice(explode('/', $export_details['link']), -1)[0];
  return view('home',compact('export_details'));  
}
```

Here are links to [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_slice()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) PHP functions for your reference.

Comment: since the response is in arrays, shouldn't your line of code be in a for loop?

Comment: Ah my bad. I missed that out. To turn it into a loop perhaps you can try:
  
foreach($export_details as &$export_detail)
{
  $export_detail['link'] = array_slice(explode('/', $export_detail['link']), -1)[0];
}

Comment: Alternatively, you may also do the same massaging inside your view (although not ideal as it can quickly dirty your view): 
<iframe src="{{ array_slice(explode('/', $export_detail['link']), -1)[0] }}" width="345" height="200" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>